# Simple getline and cin ignoring the first character

Tags: c++, cin, cout, getline

I'm trying to get these outputs separated, but the second output's first character is being ignored.

Input:

1

1 2 3

Output:

(space)2 3

Expected output...

1 2 3

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string a; cin >> a;
    string s; cin >> s;
    getline(cin, s);
    cout << s;
}
```

Comment: `cin >> s; getline(cin, s);` - what do you think this does?

Comment: Well of course. You first read `"1"` into `a`, then you read the second `"1"` into `s`, and finally you read the rest of the line (`" 2 3"`) into `s`, ***overwriting*** the contents already in `s`. And then you print `s`.

Comment: @Mat reads the whole line?

Comment: @Idk no, it reads from the current position to the end of the line, not the same thing at all.

Comment: @Idk: no. There are two statements there. What does each one do?

Comment: Well how can i get the "1 2 3" output then?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on *why* you expect the output to be `1 2 3`? And what is the real problem you want to solve? Why are you doing this?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm new to C++ and I'm used to Python. This syntax is completely new to me. Trying to solve simple problems with more inputs but... can't get the right output.

Comment: @Mat well is there a way to just do getline() for the second line? lol

Comment: Input from the standard streams is buffered. When you use the "input" or "extract" operator (as it's sometimes called) `>>` you *extract* (i.e. remove) characters from the buffer. This is what happens here, for the second line you *extract* the initial `1`, leaving the *rest* of the line for your `std::getline` call. You say that you want the output to be `1 2 3`, and so seem to expect `std::getline` to read the *whole* line, including the extracted `1`. That's just not how it works.

Comment: And it is still very unclear what your original problem is. ***Why*** do you do a separate extraction of the `1`? What problem is that supposed to solve? Please read about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and think about how your question might be one (asking for help with a solution to an unknown problem).

Answer (score 0):

This program produces the required output

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a; cin >> a;
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    cout << s;
}
```

The call to `cin.ignore()` moves to the next line, as you are still on the previous line after `cin >> a;`. You could do something like `string dummy; getline(cin, dummy);` but `ignore` avoids using an unnecessary variable.

Comment: This isn't really the problem, especially since the second `>>` operation in the OPs code will skip leading whitespace (which includes the newline from the first line). And while this solves what the OP *asks* about (as it displays the wanted output), it might not solve the *real* problem leading to the question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I took `cin >> s;` as a flawed attempt to deal with the problem that `cin.ignore(...);` solves. Only the OP can say if that is the real problem or not.

Comment: How do you *know* what the OP really wants? The OP never mentions why he or she is doing like that. Perhaps the OP need the first sub-string of the second line separately, as well as a whole line? We just don't know.